# How to store array received from server in a script variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm using express js framework and Handlebarsjs as the templating engine.
I want to send an array from the router to the view and store this array inside a script tag

```
//users is an array
res.render('chatRoom',{users:users});
```

and my chatRoom.hbs

```
<script>
var users= {{ users }}
console.log(users);
</script>
```

I'm trying to do something like this but getting this error

```
SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal
```

Help please.

Comment: To help you with this, we'd need to know A) What `users` is in the first code block, and B) What the page **actually sent to the browser** looks like (not the .hbs source).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder its an array retrived from mongo db                                          [ { _id: 5a12ba6ecb260717d3fd1ade,
    socket_id: 'NzAv4BVyARp5AGizAAAA',
    nickName: 'Des',
    __v: 0 } ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could output it as json.

There's 2 ways of doing this.
First, return json string with your view:

```
res.render('chatRoom',{users:users, usersJson:JSON.stringify(users)});
```

Then, in your `chatRoom.hbs` you can use:

Note the triple braces `{{{ }}}` - this prevents characters being 'escaped' for HTML

```
<script>
  var users = {{{ usersJson }}}
  console.log(users);
</script>
```

Or you could register a helper

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('toJSON', function(obj) {
    return JSON.stringify(obj);
});
```

Then, in your `chatRoom.hbs` you can use

```
<script>
  var users = {{{ toJSON users }}}
  console.log(users);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using triple braces may cause an HTML injection (“XSS”), what you have to do is to put your data somewhere in an attribute as json string and then parse it in your script :

Register a Helper function first:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('json', function(context) {
    return JSON.stringify(context);
});
```

Put your data in an attribute

```
<div id="users-source" data-users='{{ json user }}'></div>
<script>
    var users = JSON.parse( $('#users-source').attr('data-users') );
    console.log(users);
    // OR directly
    var users = $('#users-source').data('users');
    console.log(users);
</script>
```